# How to Find the Page the Front Page is Using?

Tags: theme-development, themes, pages, front-end, frontpage

I use WordPress [theme Shiny](http://wplayout.com/premium-wp-layout-shiny.html).  I had someone else do my site and now I am trying to figure out how to edit the homepage. The theme version is version `1.0.2`.

How can I edit my homepage?

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. This is a commercial Theme, meaning that we don't have access to the Theme files to be able to answer the question. Also, the answer is entirely specific to this Theme, and not universally beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is unrelated to your theme. WordPress has an option to set a static page as front page. To find that page go to **Settings/Reading** and see if such a page was set:

[image]

In this example the page name is **Sample Page**. If there is no static page set, you have to look through the theme options. Unfortunately, some theme authors rcreate native functions like that …

Now go to **Pages** and find that page:

[image]

You can edit it by clicking the **edit** link.

Comment: thanks for your response....but there is no static page

Comment: The theme page says there is an _Extensive Documentation included (Built Into the Admin),_ they offer support too. Ask the support if you cannot find useful information in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine which template is being used when WordPress renders your front page, try this:

1. Create a PHP file called something like `wordpress_debug_template_file.php` and place it in same directory as `functions.php` and add:

   ```
   <?php

   add_action('wp_head', 'show_template');

   function show_template() {
       global $template;
       print_r($template);
   }

   ?>
   ```
2. Next, add the following to your `functions.php` file before the ending `?>`:

   ```
   //Loads the template debugger
   require_once('wordpress_debug_template_file.php');
   ```

This will print the absolute path to the actual template file being used on all pages at the top of each page.

Just comment out the `require_once` line to turn it off.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate your response ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the current front page with the following code:

```
/* Get the current front page. */
$front_page = get_page(get_option('page_on_front'));
echo $front_page->post_title;
```

You can set a new front page by a page ID number, if you know it.

```
/* Set a new front page with a page id number. */
$page_id = '6';
update_option('page_on_front', $page_id);
```

If you don't know how to get the page ID number, don't worry about it. You can still set a front page with the title of your desired page.

```
/* Set a new front page with a page title */
update_option('page_on_front', get_page_by_title('Your Crazy Page Title'));
```